# Error while integrating Gdata to upload video on Youtube

Tags: iphone, gdata

To upload video through you tube I m integrating GData project as following the steps descibed in this link http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/

After completing all the steps I m getting errors as

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryYouTubeUpload", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in LibraryViewController.o


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaCategory", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in LibraryViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaDescription", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in LibraryViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaKeywords", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in LibraryViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaTitle", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in LibraryViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleYouTube", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in LibraryViewController.o
```

How can I fix these ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These errors you will get due to:

1) Either your implementation files or nib files are not added in your target. or
2) Any framework is missing.

for the first one, you check in the build phases for the file LibraryViewController.
and for second one go through the readMe file for GData or any header file in GData the details will be given.